# MS Access vb code to search for string (using the LIKE) statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have a from in Microsoft Access with a text box (name below is TextSerial). I want users to be able to enter in a string and have it display all matching records in a sub-form. Below is my code, but it is not working (no records come up).

```
Private Sub TextSerial_Enter()
Dim myEquipment As String
myEquipment = "Select * from tblEquipment where ([Serial] Like '% " & Me.TextSerial & " %' )"
Me.tblEquipment_subform1.Form.RecordSource = myEquipment
Me.tblEquipment_subform1.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

I have a feeling that it has something to do with the order of the quotations (' vs ") but I haven't been able to figure it out. I want the users to be able to only enter part of the string (which is why I am using Like instead of =). Thanks!

Comment: Use `Parameters` , then you can use `%`

Comment: @Sami if you are adjusting a form record source and not executing a query, I don't think you can use `parameters`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really simple answer:
Jet/ACE Like operator uses `*` as a wildcard, not `%`
Adjust the following and it should work

```
myEquipment = "Select * from tblEquipment where ([Serial] Like '*" & Me.TextSerial & "*' )"
```

Comment: Ah! I did not know that. However, no, this still doesn't bring up any results. Is there any better way to debug why not?

Comment: Ah, stupid, the spaces are ruining it I think: `myEquipment = "Select * from tblEquipment where ([Serial] Like '*" & Me.TextSerial & "*' )"` should work

Comment: That's it! That works! Only, it won't update on hitting enter. I have to go back and select the text box before it updates the subform. Is having this code run on "Enter" a bad idea?

Answer (score 3):

Two things I've noticed. First, you can use a double-double quote as a character escape (i.e. "He said ""Hello.""" will output the string: `He said "Hello"`).

Second, you have a space in the query between the wildcard and your text. I don't know if that was intentional or not, but what that means is if you are searching for a string in a field, say `ABC123`, you would not actually get a result because the extra spaces are characters not present in that record.

See if these simple changes will fix your problem.

```
myEquipment = "Select * from tblEquipment where [Serial] Like ""*" & Me.TextSerial & "*"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `*` instead of `%` as the wildcard and change the formatting slightly.

```
myEquipment = "Select * from tblEquipment where ([Serial] Like '*" & Me.TextSerial & "*' )"
```

Comment: See my answer. Your answer is incorrectly removing quotes causing Me.TextSerial not to be processed by VB.Net, thus breaking functionality.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth is right, it breaks functionality. This brings up a pop-up window. It actually works - I can search for a string and it brings up the relevant results, but the pop-up window keeps coming back up.... Is doing this on "Enter" a bad idea? Should I do a button instead?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth edited. I didn't actually mean to change the quotes, I was focusing on the `*` and removing the spaces either side of the text.